# Truly custom font in Tkinter

Tags: python, fonts, tkinter

I am making an interface in Tkinter and I need to have custom fonts.  Not just, say, Helvetica at a certain size or whatever, but fonts other than what would normally be available on any given platform.  This would be something that would be kept with the program as an image file or (preferably) Truetype font file or similar.  I don't want to have to install the desired fonts on every machine that is going to use the program, I just want to carry them around with the program in the same directory.

The tkFont module looks like it ought to do something like this, but I can't see where it would take a filename for a font not normally accessible to the system running the program.
   Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I realize this is an old question, but there is a way to do this, on Windows at least. See my answer below

Comment: First of all the accepted answer has a broken link so you might want to consider changing it.  Second, for custom fonts I would suggest looking into PyQt or PySide2.  They have support for custom fonts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found [this discussion](http://www.python-forum.org/pythonforum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=4981) where they cover how to use a line of text as an image and use PIL to place it into the window. That might be a solution.

I could not find a way to use tkFont to import a bundled font in the [tkFont man page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/font.htm).

Comment: One can't open the discussion link anymore

Comment: Yes, you're right. I can't locate an archive of the discussion either. Basically my understanding of it now is that you'd render out the text using your custom font in PIL and then place it into the window using Tkinter, but it's been a few years since I've thought about the problem :) [Here's a link on using PIL for image processing](http://codeidol.com/community/python/viewing-and-processing-images-with-pil/17565/).

Answer (score 20):

There is a way of getting external fonts into Tkinter on Windows.

The key piece of code to make this work is the following function:

```py
from ctypes import windll, byref, create_unicode_buffer, create_string_buffer
FR_PRIVATE  = 0x10
FR_NOT_ENUM = 0x20

def loadfont(fontpath, private=True, enumerable=False):
    '''
    Makes fonts located in file `fontpath` available to the font system.

    `private`     if True, other processes cannot see this font, and this
                  font will be unloaded when the process dies
    `enumerable`  if True, this font will appear when enumerating fonts

    See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183327(VS.85).aspx

    '''
    # This function was taken from
    # https://github.com/ifwe/digsby/blob/f5fe00244744aa131e07f09348d10563f3d8fa99/digsby/src/gui/native/win/winfonts.py#L15
    # This function is written for Python 2.x. For 3.x, you
    # have to convert the isinstance checks to bytes and str
    if isinstance(fontpath, str):
        pathbuf = create_string_buffer(fontpath)
        AddFontResourceEx = windll.gdi32.AddFontResourceExA
    elif isinstance(fontpath, unicode):
        pathbuf = create_unicode_buffer(fontpath)
        AddFontResourceEx = windll.gdi32.AddFontResourceExW
    else:
        raise TypeError('fontpath must be of type str or unicode')

    flags = (FR_PRIVATE if private else 0) | (FR_NOT_ENUM if not enumerable else 0)
    numFontsAdded = AddFontResourceEx(byref(pathbuf), flags, 0)
    return bool(numFontsAdded)
```

After you call `loadfont` with the path to your font file (which can be any of `.fon`, `.fnt`, `.ttf`, `.ttc`, `.fot`, `.otf`, `.mmm`, `.pfb`, or `.pfm`), you can load the font like any other installed font `tkFont.Font(family=XXX, ...)`. and use it anywhere you like. [See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183327(VS.85).aspx) for more info]

The biggest caveat here is that the family name of the font won't necessarily be the name of the file; it's embedded in the font data. Instead of trying to parse out the name, it would probably be easier to just look it up in a font browser GUI and hardcode into your application. **edit**: or, per patthoyt's comment below, look it up in `tkFont.families()` (as the last item, or, more robustly, by comparing the list of families before and after loading the font).

I found this function in [digsby](https://github.com/ifwe/digsby/blob/f5fe00244744aa131e07f09348d10563f3d8fa99/digsby/src/gui/native/win/winfonts.py#L15) ([license](https://github.com/ifwe/digsby/blob/f5fe00244744aa131e07f09348d10563f3d8fa99/LICENSE)); there's an `unloadfont` function defined there if you want to remove the font before your program finishes executing. (You can also just rely on the `private` setting to unload the font when your program ends.)

For anyone interested, [here](http://code.activestate.com/lists/tcl-core/8157/) is a discussion on this topic on [TCLCORE] from a few years ago. Some more background: [fonts on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162470(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Provided you avoid passing FR_NOT_ENUM the font name is visible in `tkinter.font.families()`. When I tested this it was appended to the end of the list so it seems likely that `tkinter.font.families()[-1]` will be the name you need to pass to Tk.

Comment: Oh nice! You could also save `tkinter.font.families()` before the call, then compare that to the result after the call to `loadfont`. Are font files restricted to one family?

Comment: Saving the families() result and using `[name for name in families() if name not in saved_list]` works nicely. If that was returned by the `loadfont` function it might be nice -- although then this function requires tkinter to be loaded. Returning the actual number of fonts might be more use than a boolean in this case. My testing font only has one face in the file.

Comment: This doesn't work for me -- I'm using Python 3 and have changed `if isinstance(fontpath, str):` to `if isinstance(fontpath, bytes):` and `elif isinstance(fontpath, unicode):` to `elif isinstance(fontpath, str):`. No new fonts are loaded...

Comment: Works fine for me in Python3

Comment: Anyone know of an equivalent way to do this on OS X?  it looks like I could just copy fonts to a certain user directory and then remove them when the app exits, but it's not clean.

Answer (score 11):

There is no way to load an external font file into Tkinter without resorting to platform-specific hacks. There's nothing built-in to Tkinter to support it.

Comment: what do you think about using `pyglet` will it work with OS X?

Comment: @CoolCloud: I have no idea. I've never used pyglet.

Answer (score 11):

this worked for me on windows but doesn't seem to work on linux:

```
import pyglet,tkinter
pyglet.font.add_file('file.ttf')

root = tkinter.Tk()
MyLabel = tkinter.Label(root,text="test",font=('font name',25))
MyLabel.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Worked for me as well. It does not install the font, just let the code use the font.

Comment: @buran yeah. when i made this i was using windows. i just tried it on Linux and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: This seems to handle sizes weird, for example `JetBrains Mono` in size 10 looks much bigger in tkinter than in PyCharm

Comment: @xjcl This should work https://stackoverflow.com/a/43046744

Answer (score 4):

[tkextrafont](https://github.com/TkinterEP/python-tkextrafont) seems to me to be the most lightweight and simple, with prebuilt wheels for Windows and Linux on PyPI. Example:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkextrafont import Font

window = tk.Tk()
font = Font(file="tests/overhaul.ttf", family="Overhaul")
tk.Label(window, text="Hello", font=font).pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: how did you install tkextrafont because i cant seem to get it to work

Comment: @MagicThanos see this pypi page: https://pypi.org/project/tkextrafont/ It also have examples provided

Comment: i did that but i have to specify a path in the settings.json for it to work

Answer (score 3):

This was a simple solution for me:

```
import pyglet, tkinter
pyglet.font.add_file("your font path here")
#then you can use the font as you would normally
```

Answer (score 1):

for linux, I was able to install the `otf` font file I had into the system fonts directory:

```
mkdir /usr/share/fonts/opentype/my_fonts_name
cp ~/Downloads/my_fonts_name.otf /usr/share/fonts/opentype/my_fonts_name/
```

I found this home directory worked, and ended up using it instead:

```
mkdir ~/.fonts/
cp ~/Downloads/my_fonts_name.otf ~/.fonts/
```

in either case, then I could load it using a string of the font-name (as all the tkinter docs show):

```
# unshown code
self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.data_frame, background="black")
self.canvas.create_text(event.x, event.y, text=t, tags='clicks', 
                        fill='firebrick1',
                        font=("My Fonts Name", 22))
```

Answer (score 1):

For future people that come across this question, that want a very simple solution and implementation that works cross-platform. This answer is probably an answer discussed in the invalid link on August 16, 2012. You can use PIL's `ImageFont.truetype()` to render the font, then use `Image.new()` and `ImageDraw.Draw`. I have put it into a class.

```
class RenderFont:
    def __init__(self, filename, fill=(0, 0, 0):
        """
        constructor for RenderFont
        filename: the filename to the ttf font file
        fill: the color of the text
        """
        self._file = filename
        self._fill = fill
        self._image = None
        
    def get_render(self, font_size, txt, type_="normal"):
        """
        returns a transparent PIL image that contains the text
        font_size: the size of text
        txt: the actual text
        type_: the type of the text, "normal" or "bold"
        """
        if type(txt) is not str:
            raise TypeError("text must be a string")

        if type(font_size) is not int:
            raise TypeError("font_size must be a int")

        width = len(txt)*font_size
        height = font_size+5

        font = ImageFont.truetype(font=self._file, size=font_size)
        self._image = Image.new(mode='RGBA', size=(width, height), color=(255, 255, 255))

        rgba_data = self._image.getdata()
        newdata = []

        for item in rgba_data:
            if item[0] == 255 and item[1] == 255 and item[2] == 255:
                newdata.append((255, 255, 255, 0))

            else:
                newdata.append(item)

        self._image.putdata(newdata)

        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im=self._image)

        if type_ == "normal":
            draw.text(xy=(width/2, height/2), text=txt, font=font, fill=self._fill, anchor='mm')
        elif type_ == "bold":
            draw.text(xy=(width/2, height/2), text=txt, font=font, fill=self._fill, anchor='mm', 
            stroke_width=1, stroke_fill=self._fill)

        return self._image
```

Comment: Nice solution without any extra imports, you have to `from PIL import ImageFont, ImageDraw` in your tk app in order to make this work