# Error in loading custom font file for tkinter

Tags: python, windows, fonts, tkinter

Following the question-
[Truly custom font in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993290/truly-custom-font-in-tkinter),
I tried this code (changing to str and bytes for python 3.x as instructed):

```
FR_PRIVATE  = 0x10
FR_NOT_ENUM = 0x20
def loadfont(fontpath, private=True, enumerable=False):
    # This function was taken from
    # https://github.com/ifwe/digsby/blob/f5fe00244744aa131e07f09348d10563f3d8fa99/digsby/src/gui/native/win/winfonts.py#L15
    # This function is written for Python 2.x. For 3.x, you
    # have to convert the isinstance checks to bytes and str
    if isinstance(fontpath, bytes):
        pathbuf = create_string_buffer(fontpath)
        AddFontResourceEx = windll.gdi32.AddFontResourceExA
    elif isinstance(fontpath, str):
        pathbuf = create_unicode_buffer(fontpath)
        AddFontResourceEx = windll.gdi32.AddFontResourceExW
    else:
        raise TypeError('fontpath must be of type str or unicode')
    flags = (FR_PRIVATE if private else 0) | (FR_NOT_ENUM if not enumerable else 0)
    numFontsAdded = AddFontResourceEx(byref(pathbuf), flags, 0)
    return bool(numFontsAdded)
root = tkinter.Tk()
first =  tkinter.font.families()
print(loadfont("Interface/FONTS/BebasNeue.otf"))
second = tkinter.font.families()
print(first==second)
print([x for x in second if x not in first])
root.mainloop()
```

(*I put tkinter.font.families() in the window as it only works in the context of a window*)

The output was:

```
True
[]
```

I tried swapping the instance str & bytes but this throws an error as well.
I've looked everywhere and I can't find an answer.

---

### UPDATE

The script actually did work, although the font did not show up in `font.families()`. My mistake was assuming that the `font.families()` was referencing the environmental fonts and would be updated, when *I think* it was referencing a variable assigned on the initialisation of the module. When I used it as a font in a test window, it worked perfectly.

Comment: I have the same problem; did you solve it eventually?

Comment: No; I would have commented on the original question but I didn't have enough reputation points or whatever

Comment: `first =  tkinter.font.families()`

`AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'font'`