# How to use Segoe font in a Tkinter label?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to give a modern look to my tkinter GUI. Here is the syntax I am using without any luck. Any help will be greatly helpful!

```
from Tkinter import *
my_font=("Segoe UI", 20, "bold")

root =Tk()
root.geometry("800x480)
Label=(root, text="my label", font = my_font).place(x=320, y=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: no errors, but the font is non responsive. So essentially it does not change to segoe like we would expect

Comment: Which OS are you on? Some *nix systems don't have MS fonts installed by default. And `tkinter` does not raise an error when it doesn't find a font. It just reverts to the default font.

Comment: Ok, then please edit your question with the real code (without typos) and, if possible, share a screenshot of your GUI's output.

Comment: @Veejay The code you've posted is broken (possibly not corresponding to the code you've tested) — as was mentioned by Billal in a question they've (prematurely?) deleted, the string `"800x480"` was not closed and the syntax for label instantiation is wrong (maybe `Label(...` without the equal sign?).  Please [edit] your question so that people can focus on your real issue and not on a red herring.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is going to address two points

1. which font families you can use immediately in `tkinter` and
2. what you can do if the family you'd like to use is not immediately available.

#### Available Font Families

*Python 2*

```
>>> from Tkinter import Tk
>>> from tkFont import families
>>> Tk(); available = families()   ### Tk() is needed to have a running tcl interpreter
<Tkinter.Tk instance at 0x7f977bcbfb90>
>>> len(available)
3011
```

*Python 3*

```
>>> from tkinter import Tk
>>> from tkinter.font import families
>>> Tk() ; available = families()
<tkinter.Tk object .>
>>> len(available)
68
```

at this point you can examine the fonts that are available printing, sorting slicing etc the contents of `available` — nb the names listed are the names that you have to use in the font definition tuple as in your example code.

#### Adding Fonts

As far as I can tell, this could be done in general as a system dependent (complicated) hack and the only published one is *ONLY* for Windows.

Said hack (I'll repeat: Windows only) is reported in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30631309/2749397).

I don't know how to proceed in general.

---

*Footnote*

3011 font families for Python 2 and 68 for Python 3? yes, Python 2 is the system Python installed by `apt` on my Debian pc, while Python 3 is Anaconda's one and sees just the fonts that Anaconda installed in its private tree.

Comment: This is great. Thank you so much :)