# How to use custom fonts on TKINTER

Tags: python-3.x, macos, user-interface, tkinter, fonts

Im trying to get a good gui for python and tkinter is working fine but I cant put any custom fonts on it

Can I import any custom fonts from either a ttf or maybe google font if not do you know any other guis that do, do that. (btw it needs to work with linux windows and osX)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truly custom font in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993290/truly-custom-font-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tkinter provides no cross-platform way to install custom fonts. The only support tkinter has built-in is to use the fonts provided by the OS.