# How to use google font in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Is There any way to use google custom fonts in Tkinter Application.
I have google Font zip file from google font and I want to use that in my tkinter application.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993290/truly-custom-font-in-tkinter/30631309#30631309. This should help.

Comment: Try [`pyglet.font.add_file(font_path)`](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/font.html#pyglet.font.add_file) from `pyglet` module.

Answer (score 0):

I've came to the same problem, unfortunately it doesn't seem to be possible to use custom fonts in traditional way anyways.

But I came to a workaround by making a image with that text onto it.

```
def create_text_image(self, text, color_rgba_code_tuple):
        fnt = Enums.ImageFont.truetype(Enums.FONT_DEFAULT, Enums.FONT_SIZE)
        text_width, text_height = fnt.getsize(text)

        img = Enums.Image.new('RGBA', (text_width,text_height))
        d = Enums.ImageDraw.Draw(img)
        d.text((0,0), text, font=fnt,fill=color_rgba_code_tuple)
        img.save(Enums.FONT_TEMPORARY_IMAGE_PATH)
        return Enums.PhotoImage(file=Enums.FONT_TEMPORARY_IMAGE_PATH)
```

**Imports**

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageTk
```

**Explanation**

You need to pass in your text and rgba tuple into the function; so, something like (255,255,255,255) for white text.

And then simply add that image that the function returns to a list, and use it in wherever place you want (like Canvas for example).

Hope this is clear.

Comment: Its not clear what `Enums` is and should be part of the answer as it is requiered for your snippet.

Comment: This is just where I store all of my imports and other variables that I don't use here.