# Custom (external from file) font in tkinter for MacOSX

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tkinter, fonts

I'm trying to write an application in Python (3.12 to be specific) that uses specific (custom) font from external file. I have no problem with this on Windows and Linux, but unfortunately, I'm unable to find any elegant solution which works on MacOS. Is there any way to do this?

I found similar questions, but the solutions are mostly for Windows and Linux. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but [solution with "pyglet"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61353191) doesn't work for me. I also failed trying to install tkextrafont package using pip (it seems that it doesn't work on MacOS)