Problem using True Type Font files in tkinter
I am trying to create a Tkinter application that uses a custom font from Google Fonts. Here is the link to the font I am using: Font Page. I have searched online for a way to change the font in Tkinter, but none of the solutions I found seem to work. Below is the most reasonable and understandable code I have found so far, but it does not seem to apply the custom font correctly.
import pyglet,tkinter
pyglet.font.add_file(r"C:\Users\Will\Downloads\Exan-Regular.ttf")

root = tkinter.Tk()
MyLabel = tkinter.Label(root,text="test",font=('Exan-Regular',25))
MyLabel.pack()
root.mainloop()


I have also tried using ChatGPT for help, but it couldn't provide a solution. Additionally, I have looked at several Stack Overflow posts, like this one, but they haven't resolved my issue either.
Can anyone help me understand what might be going wrong or provide a working example of how to use a custom Google Font in a Tkinter application?
Thank you!

Please link to the official Google Webfont URL (although it does not look like it's a Google Fonts font at all, so... whatever is its official url) not a dropbox. Having said that, you're using the filename instead of the actual font name, so check the font to see what it's "normal" name is, and use that in your font tuple. And of course: don't use ChatGPT to understand what you're doing wrong, ChatGPT can't explain anything because it doesn't know anything. It can only write you stories that sound reasonable by just generating text one word at a time.

(As for the SO post you link to: read all the answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61353191/740553 basically tells you the same thing as I did: use the font name)

Do you use windows, than this shoul work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61353191/12621346

For Windows 7 or above, pyglet uses pyglet.font.directwrite.Win32DirectWriteFont class by default which does not work with tkinter.  pyglet.font.win32.GDIPlusFont should be used instead by setting pyglet.options['win32_gdi_font'] = True.
Also the font name should be "Exan" instead of "Exan-Regular".
import pyglet, tkinter

# use GDI font
pyglet.options['win32_gdi_font'] = True
pyglet.font.add_file("C:/Users/Will/Downloads/Exan-Regular.ttf")

root = tkinter.Tk()
# font name is "Exan"
MyLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text="Testing 0123", font=('Exan', 25))
MyLabel.pack()
root.mainloop()

Result:


import ImageFont from the PIL module. Rest of the procedure is explained as comments in the code
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font as f
from PIL import ImageFont as imf

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x400')

# path to your ttf file. Change the path for your requirement
ttf_path = "/home/muthu/Downloads/elephant-2/Elephant-PersonalUse.ttf"

# Load the font
pil_font = imf.truetype(ttf_path, size=20)

# Create a font object for Tkinter using the font metrics from PIL
tk_font = f.Font(family=pil_font.getname()[0], size=20)

label = Label(root, text="HELLO !", font=tk_font)
label.pack(pady=20, padx=20)

root.mainloop()


